# When to session.commit() in a NiFi Processor

Tags: apache-nifi

I am implementing a NiFi processor and have couple of clarifications to make with respect to best practices:

1. session.getProvenanceReporter().modify(...) - Should we emit the event immediately after every session.transfer()
2. session.commit() - Documentation says, after performing operations on flowfiles, either commit or rollback can be invoked.

Developer guide: https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/html/developer-guide.html#process_session

Question is, what do I lose by not invoking these methods explicitly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1) Yes typically the provenance event is emitted after transferring the flow file.

2) It depends if you are extending AbstractProcessor, or AbstractSessionFactoryProcessor. AbstractProcessor will call commit or rollback for you so you don't need to, AbstractSessionFactoryProcessor requires you to call them appropriately.

If you are extending AbstractSessionFactoryProcessor and never call commit, eventually that session will get garbage collected and rollback will be called, and all the operations performed by that session will be rolled back.

There is also an annotation @SupportsBatching which can be placed on a processor. When this annotation is present, the UI shows a slider on the processor's scheduling tab that indicates how many milliseconds worth of framework operations like commit() can be batched together behind the scenes for increased throughput. If latency is more important then leaving the slides at 0 milliseconds is appropriate, but the key here is that the user gets to decide this when building the flow and configuring the processor.